# How to backup just pages from my site, but not posts with other post_type values

Tags: pages, database, backup

I want to backup just pages from my site, but not posts with other post_type values, so my **first question** is – will this do the trick?

1. enter cPanel phpMyAdmin
2. filter the table wp_posts for post_type=page
3. export it as a SQL command
4. in case of need, import that SQL command

My knowledge of SQL is basic (and PHP zero), so I’m afraid exported SQL command on import will drop the table and create a new table just with backed-up pages, while my intention is to insert/overwrite backed-up pages and keep everything else in the table as it was.

My **second question**: is the whole content of a page in this table, or maybe some parts are kept in some other WP tables and interconnected through IDs with wp_posts? In other words, is manipulating wp_posts enough for backup and restore of pages?

**3rd question** – I found no plugin that is doing exactly this job, or that can be easily modified to do it. Do you know any?

Or, is there some other way this SQL job can be automatized on WordPress or cPanel?

Comment: Using the built in export will not do the trick? under tools > export?

Comment: this is the problem: "I’m afraid exported SQL command on **import** will drop the table and create a new table just with backed-up pages, while my intention is to insert/overwrite backed-up pages and keep everything else in the table as it was."